# How to add dashboard Graphs to new user

Tags: opportunity, dashboard, graph

I just added a user to our salesforce, but the Gauge Dashboard  dosen't show their name and they don't see the graph in their home page. Is there a place that I need to add them to so the graph will show their sales. I thought it does automatically. What do I need to check on his account to make sure his numbers show on the graph? Its for closed opportunities and its working fine for everyone else.

The dashboard suppose to show , "Inside Sale Monthly Dashboard" but when they search  to find that they dont get any results at all [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for them to see the dashboard, you can log in as them from their user record (if you have this feature enabled), and then go to the Dashboards tab, and then view the Dashboard in question. The home page dashboard defaults to the last dashboard viewed. You can also go to Home and click "Customize Page" which will allow you to set the Home dashboard there. If you cannot log in as one of your users, then walk them through this process.

As to why the user is not appearing in the Closed Opportunities report, it is because they do not have any closed opportunities yet. Assuming this is a standard report type on the Opportunities object, they will appear once they have data that meets the conditions of the report.

Comment: Hey, thank for the respond, the person has already done few closed opportunities .  he is suppose to show up in there , but his dashboard page seems to not seeing any of the dashboards, I just updated the question again

Comment: Without knowing the conditions of the report that's generating that gauge, I can't see what the problem is. Have you refreshed the dashboard since he closed the opportunities? Do the opportunities appear in the report but not the dashboard? It also looks like the gauge is showing $55 worth of closed opportunities, it just appears insignificant next to the scale of $24,000.

Comment: hey, no that one is just a pic I took from my own screen, his name or numbers doesnt show on the report. it seems like he is not connected to the report at all, or has no permission, can you have no permission to see or view a report, . They are sales agent and started working and they have few closed opportunities.

Comment: His dashboard screen shows just general dashboards. but he has to see  "Inside Sale Monthly Dashboard" when I search in their search box where it says find dashboard, I get no resualts for  , I dont understand how he is not included, his profile and role is exact same as other people that it shows the dashboard

Comment: Do I need to include him in reports, or create reports for him?

Comment: If he cannot see the dashboard when logged in, then there are security settings preventing him from viewing it. Let's take this issue first. The issue of his data missing from the report is separate.

Comment: You should first take a look at the folder in which the dashboard is stored to see what the security settings are. Go to Reports, then find the folder in which this dashboard is stored. Click on the pushpin next to the folder and select edit. What are the sharing settings for the folder? If it is not being shared with all users, then what groups or roles have access. Next, determine if he is in those groups or roles.

Comment: Wow thank you very much "Click on the pushpin next to the folder and select Share"  Their name wasnt there at all . I just added their name.  Do I need to make them reports , or as soon as I do that the system will make reports for them. This dashboard is for inside sales people. there are few people already in this dashboard , which contains few different reports with different graphs.  I have to wait few minutes and test that on their machine . I cant login as them right now

Comment: You can give them access to existing reports and dashboards as I indicated above. If you have more questions about reporting, you should either take a look at the Salesforce reporting documentation https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewQuickStarts?id=000113375 or post another, more specific, question. If this answer was helpful, please vote it up and mark as the solution.